# ./downloadFabric.sh unexpected fault address 0x183e42838582

Tags: docker, go

When I am executing this command: `./downloadFabric.sh`. The error:

```
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'downloadFabric.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv11
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)
unexpected fault address 0x183e42838582
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x183e42838582 pc=0x183e42838582]

goroutine 17 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x664da8, 0x5)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:527 +0x90 fp=0xc820041928 sp=0xc820041910
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sigpanic_unix.go:27 +0x2ba fp=0xc820041978 sp=0xc820041928
net/http.(*Transport).dial(0xc82007a630, 0x666de8, 0x3, 0xc820302820, 0x17, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:499 +0x79 fp=0xc8200419c0 sp=0xc820041978
net/http.(*Transport).dialConn(0xc82007a630, 0x0, 0x665378, 0x4, 0xc820302820, 0x17, 0xc82018ae40, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:596 +0x19a9 fp=0xc820041f00 sp=0xc8200419c0
net/http.(*Transport).getConn.func4(0xc82007a630, 0x0, 0x665378, 0x4, 0xc820302820, 0x17, 0xc8203320c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:549 +0x66 fp=0xc820041f78 sp=0xc820041f00
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1721 +0x1 fp=0xc820041f80 sp=0xc820041f78
created by net/http.(*Transport).getConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:551 +0x265

goroutine 1 [select]:
net/http.(*Transport).getConn(0xc82007a630, 0xc82033c000, 0x0, 0x665378, 0x4, 0xc820302820, 0x17, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:554 +0x663
net/http.(*Transport).RoundTrip(0xc82007a630, 0xc82033c000, 0xb2, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:228 +0x4ac
net/http.send(0xc82033c000, 0xbf3548, 0xc82007a630, 0xc8203064d0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:220 +0x52c
net/http.(*Client).send(0xc820261c50, 0xc82033c000, 0x68, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:143 +0x15a
net/http.(*Client).doFollowingRedirects(0xc820261c50, 0xc82033c000, 0x776560, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:380 +0xbc0
net/http.(*Client).Do(0xc820261c50, 0xc82033c000, 0xc, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:178 +0x188
github.com/docker/engine-api/client.(*Client).sendClientRequest(0xc8202b6cb0, 0x6630e0, 0x4, 0x66a7b0, 0xe, 0xc82030a810, 0xbf8438, 0xc820306380, 0xc82030a840, 0x5fe7e0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/src/github.com/docker/engine-api/client/request.go:91 +0x3cd
github.com/docker/engine-api/client.(*Client).sendRequest(0xc8202b6cb0, 0x6630e0, 0x4, 0x66a7b0, 0xe, 0xc82030a810, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc82030a840, 0x958e00, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/src/github.com/docker/engine-api/client/request.go:69 +0x296
github.com/docker/engine-api/client.(*Client).post(0xc8202b6cb0, 0x66a7b0, 0xe, 0xc82030a810, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc82030a840, 0x20, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/src/github.com/docker/engine-api/client/request.go:33 +0x94
github.com/docker/engine-api/client.(*Client).tryImageCreate(0xc8202b6cb0, 0xc82030a810, 0xc820302760, 0x20, 0xc82030a810, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/src/github.com/docker/engine-api/client/image_create.go:25 +0x14c
github.com/docker/engine-api/client.(*Client).ImagePull(0xc8202b6cb0, 0xc82030a690, 0x24, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc820302760, 0x20, 0xc82030a660, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/vendor/src/github.com/docker/engine-api/client/image_pull.go:22 +0x2b1
github.com/docker/docker/api/client.(*DockerCli).imagePullPrivileged(0xc8201a4d00, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/api/client/pull.go:80 +0x155
github.com/docker/docker/api/client.(*DockerCli).CmdPull(0xc8201a4d00, 0xc82000a230, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/api/client/pull.go:65 +0xa3c
reflect.callMethod(0xc820261cb0, 0xc820145c28)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:628 +0x1fc
reflect.methodValueCall(0xc82000a230, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc820261cb0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc820261cb0, 0x0, 0x66834, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/asm_amd64.s:29 +0x36
github.com/docker/docker/cli.(*Cli).Run(0xc820261800, 0xc82000a220, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/cli/cli.go:89 +0x383
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/docker/docker.go:63 +0x43c

goroutine 5 [syscall]:
os/signal.loop()
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x18
created by os/signal.init.1
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x37

goroutine 7 [runnable]:
runtime.SetFinalizer(0x64f540, 0xc8202b6ee0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mfinal.go:261
net.(*netFD).destroy(0xc8202b6ee0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:137 +0x7e
net.(*netFD).decref(0xc8202b6ee0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:153 +0x40
net.(*netFD).Close(0xc8202b6ee0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:199 +0x87
net.(*conn).Close(0xc82002c418, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:196 +0xab
net/http.(*persistConn).closeLocked(0xc820094210)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1248 +0x4e
net/http.(*persistConn).close(0xc820094210)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1242 +0x7a
net/http.(*persistConn).readLoop(0xc820094210)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1004 +0x954
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:685 +0xc78

goroutine 8 [select]:
net/http.(*persistConn).writeLoop(0xc820094210)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1009 +0x40c
created by net/http.(*Transport).dialConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:686 +0xc9d
```

Version used: go version 1.10.3

Operating System and version (desktop or mobile): Mac OS 10.13.6

Comment: This looks like an issue with docker, not an issue with hyperledger fabric or hyperledger composer, might be worth changing the tags to reflect this.

Comment: @david_k So how to fix this issue? I have docker running on the menu bar.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea. Personally I don't bother with running docker on a mac since all it does is use a linux VM under the covers. I just prefer to work directly with my own linux VM.